# Manager set out of office

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook

I was wondering if it was possible to have managers set out of office in outlook, for those they manage.  Almost every day I have to login into EMC and give myself full permission to someones mailbox and remove it when done.  It's a really big pain, and I'm hoping that there is an easier way to do this, and a way that can have there managers do it.

Comment: [A very similar question was asked back in 2009](http://serverfault.com/questions/76376/setting-out-of-office-message-for-someone-else) -- Do any of those options work for you (particularly the powershell one)?  Also note that IMHO the better solution is to ***educate your users*** so they set their own out of office messages: Server admins and managers aren't supposed to be nannies, and if you do it for them now they'll refuse to learn how later...

Answer (score 4):

Why grant yourself full mailbox access, when you have the ability to utilize Powershell and Exchange specific Cmdlet's (assuming you are running an Exchange 2010 organization)?

The Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration is the way forward, I would say: 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217.aspx

To answer your question regarding the possibility to delegate the steps towards a specific group: if you utilize RBAC and assign the necessary people the necessary rights, you can delegate any Exchange related step with great ease. But inline with the response already given, I would also invest in education of the (end)users.